# Error when trying to reset password in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error when trying to reset password in Laravel.

I am also not receiving a reset password email.

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input

View template for Reset password already exist!
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you add the Laravel version to the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check "**Auth**" folder from **App\Http\Controllers**. There are files answering for login and sign In processes. If you are running Laravel local, you will not recieve any email till you dont configured all data...